# A question about Infinitesimal generator of Feller Process

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $S=%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
$, and consider the Feller process $\left( X_{t}\right) _{t\geq 0}$ with
state space $S$ such that $X_{t}=t+X_{0}$ for all $t\geq 0$. Let $A$ be the
infinitesimal generator of $\left( X_{t}\right) _{t\geq 0}.$ Show that $%
D\left( A\right) =\left\{ f\in C\left( S\right) :f^{\prime }\in C\left(
S\right) \right\} $ and $Af=f^{\prime }$ for all $f\in D\left( A\right) .$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows directly from the definition of the infinitesimal generator, and from the definition of the derivative.

1. Derive the semigroup $P_t$ associated to $X_t$. Prove that $P_tf(x) = f(x+t)$ for any Borel $f$.
2. By the definition of the infinitesimal generator,
   $$
     \mathscr Af(x):=\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\frac{P_tf(x) - f(x)}{t} = \lim_{t\downarrow 0}\frac{f(x+t) - f(x)}{t} = f'(x) \tag{1}
   $$
   whenever $f$ has a derivative at $x$. As a result, you see that to belong to $D(\mathscr A)$ the function has to have a derivative pointwise everywhere.
3. Since $D(\mathscr A)$ is the set of all functions for which the convergence in $(1)$ is uniform, you get that $f'$ has to be a continuous function. Indeed, you have that $g(x,t) := \frac{f(x+t) - f(x)}{t}$ that are continuous functions converge uniformly to $f'$. As a result, the latter function has to be continuous as well.

I have an impression though, that $f'$ also has to be bounded - which you may wanna check by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the post! I tried a similar method and it works!

Comment: @BigMike: that's nice :)